# SQL Server setting up logins for backup site

Tags: sql-server

I am setting up a second SQL Server for a backup site.
I am using SSIS to transfer user logins from production to site2.

I was wondering whether I should transfer the NT Service,NT AUTHORITY and ###MS****### logins from one server to the other or set those up separately on site 2 ?

Comment: Aren't those logins created when you install SQL Server?

Comment: yes they are but they aren't enabled and I wasn't sure if I needed the same credentials for a fail-over site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was wondering whether I should transfer the NT Service,NT AUTHORITY and ###MS****### logins from one server to the other

No need to transfer those logins, because they are created automatically when you install new SQL Server instance

By the way, easiest way to transfer other logins from one server to another, is to use `sp_help_revlogin` procedure:

[How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server)